# How to swap values in python?

Tags: python, list, variables, numbers, swap

I know how to swap two variables together but I want to know if there is a quicker way to follow a certain pattern.

So I have this list of number. `list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
And what I want to do is to swap a number with the following one and swap the next number with the number after it.                                                                                                 so after swapping them it would become `list=[2,1,4,3,6,3]` 
So I was wondering if there was a way to be able to swap the numbers more simply. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `[2,1,4,3,6,5]` ?

Comment: You're looking for a "quicker way" than what? What have you got so far?

Comment: `list[0], list[1] = list[1], list[0]` with tuple assignment works

Comment: >>> t= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> index1 = t.index(1)
>>> index2 = t.index(2)
>>> t[index1], t[index2] = 2,1
>>> t

Comment: The reason why I want something quicker is because i have around 20 numbers to swap so it will take a long time and I need something that is simple to be easily explained

Answer (score 8):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # As an example
for x in range(0, len(lst), 2):
    if x+1 == len(lst): # A fix for lists which have an odd-length
        break 
    lst[x], lst[x+1] = lst[x+1], lst[x]
```

This doesn't create a new list.

Edit: Tested and it's even faster than a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very easy method and if possible would you be able to explain what is going on. Thank you so much.

Comment: This code basically swaps each two elements in the list, that's why I've provided a third argument to range(). The "If statement" Is necessary for odd-lengthed lists, as at one point the loop reaches the last element in the list and there isn't there an element next to it to perform the swapping, which part of the code you don't understand?

Comment: Yeah I understood that it swaps two elements together. 
for x in range(0, len(lst), 2): 
This is the part that I'm a bit confused about but that could be due to myself not knowing much about for loop. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: And also about what the x+1 stands for? I'm sorry. I'm kinda new to python so there is a lot that I don't know yet. So thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The list [1,2,3,4,5,6] has got 6 elements, so It has a length of 6, so range(0, len(lst), 2) == range(0, 6, 2) - I think you know what range(0,6) does, It returns a list which contains [0,1,2,3,4,5], range(0,6,2) does the same but it instead returns a list which contains [0, 2, 4], in other words it skips every other element thus returning half the number of elements in the original list

Comment: x +1 Is the next element in the list, simple as that, the "if" statement  checks if there isn't a next element , If there isn't a next element then It breaks out of the loop (ends it).

Comment: I'd start the range at 1 and then swap elements x and x-1. Then you don't need the if+break. (Though for even-length lists I still prefer my solution, as it's significantly shorter and faster.)

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann I don't think that approach would work for even-lengthed lists, as for your solution, I don't think it is faster, it is a list comprehension which creates another list, I have made some tests with similiar piece of codes and found out that creating another list steals too much performance, but It's more readable and shorter.

Comment: @no_name Why would that not work for even lengths? It does. And that list comprehension *is* significantly faster, [have a look here](http://ideone.com/ZTruX0) for a test and its results (on the bottom of the page).

Comment: You're right, I was In hurry when I posted that comment.

Answer (score 2):

If your list has even length, this might be the simplest way:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [lst[i^1] for i in range(len(lst))]
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Comment: what if it has odd length

Comment: Darn... ok I don't really want to handle that, will just say that this requires an even length (which could always be true for him).

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
from itertools import izip_longest

In [115]: li
Out[115]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [116]: [i for i in list(chain(*(izip_longest(li[1::2],li[0::2])))) if i!=None]
Out[116]: [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7]
```

or alternatively if you have even length list

```
a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step
```

Check this Understanding [List slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

```
In [65]: li
Out[65]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [66]: new=[None]*(len(li))

In [71]: new[0::2]=li[1::2]

In [73]: new[1::2]=li[0::2]

In [74]: new
Out[74]: [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very easy method and if possible would you be able to explain what is going on. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses [funcy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy)

**Example:**

```
>>> from funcy import chunks, mapcat
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> ys = mapcat(reversed, chunks(2, xs))
>>> ys
[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

This  kinds of reads nicely too; concatenate and map the results of reversing each 2-pair chunks of `xs`.